# How do i define a function/macro that calls a specific data frame column in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that calls a specific column from a pandas DataFrame that I have defined earlier in my code.

The dataframe can be something simple, such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                        {
                        'col0': np.random.randint(0,100,100),
                        'col1': np.random.randint(0,100,100),
                        'col2': np.random.randint(0,100,100)
                          }
                         )
```

The next step would be to write a function that calls col0, col1, or col2.

```
def hist(x):
    return np.histogram(
                        df['x'],
                        bins = 6
                        )
```

However, when you call the function by the column name defined in the data frame, python does not recognize the name;

```
In [1]: hist(col1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-68-e860df6abc8e>", line 1, in <module>
    hist(col1)

NameError: name 'col1' is not defined
```

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: You've giot mixed up variable names an strings.  `df['x']` must be `df[x]`, and `col1` in the function call must be `"col1"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up strings and variables. You probably want something like

```
def hist(x):
    return np.histogram(
                        df[x], # no quotes! You want the value of x here, not a literal "x"
                        bins = 6
                        )
```

and call it like this:

```
foo = hist('col1')   # quotes necessary since you're passing the string "col1"
```

Otherwise, Python looks for a variable named `col1`, and that hasn't been defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the x's quotation marks and put a string as the function input with the name of the column:

```
def hist(x):
    return np.histogram(df[x], bins = 6)

hist('col1')
```